# GetMethods with GetCustomAttributes

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

Situation:
Currently I am reading all available functions and methods from specific class with reflection. All the functions in the class does have an attribute section like this

```
[ImportFunctionAttribute("myFunction1", 1, ImportAttribute.SourceType.Type1)]
public ImportStatusDetails myFunction1()
{
}

[ImportFunctionAttribute("myFunction2", 2, ImportAttribute.SourceType.Type2)]
public ImportStatusDetails myFunction2()
{
}
```

To get all the methods in the given class I use this code

```
// get the public methods out of import class order by class name
var importMethods = (typeof (Import)).GetMethods(
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Problem:
Using the GetMethods-Method will give me both functions - but I only want to get the method of type ImportAttribute.SourceType.Type2.

Question:
Is it possible to limit the results of the GetMethods-Method for given CustomAttributes like for example with GetMethods(...).Where() ?? What should I do to resolve this problem?

Addition1

```
public class ImportFunctionAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public enum SourceType
        {
            Unknown = 0,
            Type1 = 1,
            Type2 = 2
        }

        public ImportFunctionAttribute(string psTabName, int pnTabId, SourceType pSourceType)
        {
            tabName = psTabName;
            tabId = pnTabId;
            source = pSourceType;
        }
        protected string tabName;
        protected int tabId;
        protected SourceType source;
        public string TabName { get { return tabName; } }
        public int TabId { get { return tabId; } }
        public SourceType Source { get { return source; } }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for GetCustomAttributes(...).

```
var methods = new List<MethodInfo>();
var importMethods = (typeof (Import)).GetMethods(
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly));

for (var i = 0; i < importMethods.Length; i++) 
{
    var attr = importMethods[i].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ImportFunctionAttribute), false).Cast<ImportFunctionAttribute>();
    if (attr.Source == SourceType.Type2)
    {
        methods.Add(importMethods[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work as Type2 is unknown at this point. I have added the Attribute-Class to the main post. Maybe it's easier for the community now to understand what I am currently trying to do. Thanks ad this point, regerory.

Comment: Gotcha. I've edited the answer. I believe this is what you need.

Comment: Yep. I had to change a little bit but now it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks, @HNITC - please mark as answer if you could. :)